# wordpress keeps redirecting on locahost when migrating from live server to localhost

Tags: wordpress, redirect, localhost

For some unknown reason my live wordpress fot blocked, showing following message on each hit
"This site has been temporarily disabled, please try again later."

So, In order to recover data I copied my wordpress site files from domain to my PC. I uploaded the database to phpmyadmin, updated the wp-config.php file for my localhost but every time when I try to hit the site from browser* i.e. "http://localhost:8080/my-site-name/" it keeps me redirecting to the url "http://localhost/my-site-name/"

*my localhost is set up to the port 8080

Comment: what is in your wordpress wp-config.php file , can you update here?

Comment: here is the dropbox link of my wp-config.php file https://www.dropbox.com/s/fvkhuf8me0faxad/wp-config.php?dl=0

Comment: Have you tried @Alice 's solution?

Comment: yes i've tried it

Comment: You can check a tutorial I wrote about migrating locally developed WordPress to a live site here: https://madebydenis.com/manually-migrate-locally-developed-wordpress-site-to-a-live-server/

Answer (score 7):

open database, wp_options table, find row with site_url, home_url.... it's using old value, change them with new address.

Comment: check you files now.. in root directory you have a .htaccess file.... look for old address there too... If any, replace them

Comment: also your config.php, I can see

define('WP_HOME','http://localhost:8080/digitech360/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost:8080/digitech360/');

update these lines with new URL

Comment: these urls are my actual urls which includes localhost-address:site-folder-name

Comment: are you sure in your database you have replaced all localhost with 'localhost:8080 ?

Comment: Now I am also getting confuzed, because only DB, htaccess, and config file .. these 3 you have to check.... if it is beyond tghat then some prob is there. And without investigating site code, it is difficult to guess the issue

Comment: Can you please provide me the .htccess code? i just want to match it.

Comment: It looks like  --- 
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /lycagroup/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /lycagroup/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress


By the way clear all the CACHE and COOKIE ... because old redirects do work sometime

Answer (score 1):

**Directly copying files from your live WordPress directory and import live database into local will not work as expected.**

- For this you need to updated all links in you local database with
  local server link (Use search in phpmyadmin for domain and replace
  with local one.
- You may need to updated your .htaccess file according
  your local server.
- For getting backup from live to local you use
  plug-in like `Duplicator`.

Here is a link [duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) where you will find plugin for backup and restore.It backup both php files and database.so need to import db on local mysql

Comment: I've updated all linkes in database using [interconnectit](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Comment: install duplicator on live and get backup zip and then install on local.Its simple not need any database modifications

Comment: I wish i could do it, my domain got blocked i can't even access it directly from url address (which means i can't login to my wordpress admin). I think it is due to some external injection.

Comment: It seems there may be problem with you local servers config file and port number .  AND where is you site url,what msg you get while logging?

Comment: When i enter this url "http://localhost:8080/my-site-folder/" it searches for 1 or 2 seaconds and then changes the url to "http://localhost/my-site-folder/" saying that you can not access this web page.

Comment: my localhost is working just fine because i'm doing my other projects which are running very well including phpmyadmin

Comment: try this in your themes function.php file  jusr after php tag remove_filter('template_redirect','redirect_canonical'); and then restart server before test

Answer (score 0):

There is a quick hack to this also. You can create a **dummy post** on WordPress and publish it. Later you can delete the post. It works for me the most time.